# Can't display a pdf file in my jsf2 application

Tags: pdf, jsf-2, primefaces

I try to display a pdf file on my **jsf2** application and the problem is in the path file.

My pdf file is inside a folder named **FichesPratiques** which is inside another folder named **resources** (folder **resources** is inside **WebContent**) and I use this to display it :

```
<p:media value="/resources/FichesPratiques/file.pdf" width="100%" height="300px">
```

but anything is displayed.

and more strange, when I use link below to download it, it doesn't work.

```
<h:outputLink value="/resources/FichesPratiques/file.pdf">click</h:outputLink> to download pdf instead.
```

Can someone help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look closer at the URL generated in the HTML output of those components (rightclick, *View Source* in webbrowser). In contrary to among others the `<h:graphicImage value>`, the `<p:media value>` and `<h:outputLink value>` do not prepend the web application context path in the URL. The leading `/` in the URL makes it relative to the domain root of the request URL (the one as you see in browser's address bar).

Imagine that the JSF page is been opened by

> `http://localhost:8080/somecontext/page.xhtml`

Then those `value="/resources/FichesPratiques/file.pdf"` paths would expect the resource to be present in

> `http://localhost:8080/resources/FichesPratiques/file.pdf`

However, you *actually* have it in

> `http://localhost:8080/somecontext/resources/FichesPratiques/file.pdf`

You should either be using a valid URL relative to the current request URL,

```
<p:media value="resources/FichesPratiques/file.pdf" ... />
```

or explicitly specify the context path in the URL,

```
<p:media value="#{request.contextPath}/resources/FichesPratiques/file.pdf" ... />
```